# $\frac{e^{ixt}-1}{ix} \to \frac{i}{x+i0}$ as $t\to\infty$

Tags: limits, distribution-theory

In a physics paper, I saw an expression
$$\frac{e^{ixt}-1}{ix} \to \frac{i}{x+i0}, \quad t\to\infty,$$
without any further explanation. I think this expression should be regarded as a distribution sense, but I cannot figure out why it is true. Introducing a test function $f\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb R)$, we should evaluate
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{e^{ixt}-1}{ix} f(x)dx.$$
How should one proceeded? Writing $f(x) = f(0) + xg(x)$ for some function $g$ does not help.

Comment: Are you aware of the definitions of $(x\pm i0)^{-1}$ ? Use the substitution $y=xt$ before taking the limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to think of it is as a limit of a Fourier transform:
$$
\frac{e^{ixt}-1}{ix}
= \int_{0}^{t} e^{ixs} \, ds
= \int_{-t}^{0} e^{-ixs} \, ds
= \mathcal{F}\{ \mathbf{1}_{[-t,0]}(s) \}(x)
\\
\to \mathcal{F}\{ 1-u(s) \}(x)
= 2\pi\delta(x) - \pi \left( \operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{i\pi x} + \delta(x) \right)
\\
= \pi\delta(x) - \operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{ix}
,
$$
where $\mathbf{1}_{[-t,0]}(s)$ is the indicator function on the interval $[-t,0]$ and $u$ is the Heaviside step function.

Comment: That is an elegant answer. Thanks!